# NSNotificationCenter: removeAllObserver for self works for several observing objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

Say if I have several:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(notificationReceived:)
                                                 name:NotificationA
                                               object:self.player];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(notificationReceived:)
                                                 name:NotificationB
                                               object:self.player];
```

The objects are all `self.player` but for different notifications, in the end I do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

Is this fine or do I have to use the full method to remove observer for each notification? Currently I'm having issue when the view controller is unloaded but `player` is still playing in background.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you calling `removeObserver`, i mean in which method?

Comment: @Deepesh Hi I call it in viewDidUnload and viewWillDisappear

Comment: Your code seems Ok, It should work. viewDidUnload is deprecated in IOS6 but then you are using `removeObserver` in `viewWillDisappear` as well so i dont see any problem with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) say: "removeObserver: Removes all the entries specifying a given observer from the receiver’s dispatch table." So your method call is enough.